# Tengo problemas al iniciar el servidor en un proyecto en node js creado con TypeORM

Tags: mysql, nodejs, typescript, typeorm

Hola estimados buenas tardes, estoy creando un proyecto en Node js con typeORM, quiero armarme un servidor y tenerlo conectado a una base de datos Mysql y para ello ya instale express, database mysql y ciertos types que necesito, he hecho algunas configuraciones iniciales pero la verdad el error que se me presento me tiene bastante perdido, soy algo nuevo en node js. Resulta que apenas ejecute `npm run dev` para correr el servidor, me salio el siguiente error:

```
> adminlte-server@0.0.1 dev
> set debug=* && ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/index.ts

[INFO] 22:20:42 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.6.3)
Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\src\driver\mysql\MysqlDriver.ts:1171:18       
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\src\driver\mysql\MysqlDriver.ts:1168:16)
    at MysqlDriver.connect (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\src\driver\mysql\MysqlDriver.ts:387:36)
    at DataSource.initialize (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:229:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\src\index.ts:8:15) {      
  code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
  errno: 1251,
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  errno: 1251,
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  fatal: true
}
```

Este es el codigo de mi packaje.json:

```
{
   "name": "adminlte-server",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
   "type": "commonjs",
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
      "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
      "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
      "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
      "@types/node": "^16.11.26",
      "ts-node": "10.4.0",
      "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
      "typescript": "^4.6.3"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
      "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
      "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
      "cors": "^2.8.5",
      "express": "^4.17.2",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
      "mysql": "^2.14.1",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
      "typeorm": "0.3.4"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "dev": "set debug=* && ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/index.ts"
   }
}
```

Asi tengo el archivo tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "rootDir": "./src",//Esta carpeta va hacer enlace con src
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

Y este es el ormconfig.json que aproposito me toco crear manualmente el archivo y agregarle su configuracion porque no se me creo junto al proyecto:

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
    "database": "adminlted",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": false,
    "entities": [
        "src/entity/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
        "src/migration/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
        "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
        "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
        "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
    }
 }
```

Esta es la estructura que lleva el proyecto, apenas he instalado las diferentes dependencias:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edit:** desinstale la dependencia de mysql e instale mysql2 y ahora me sale este error:

```
PS C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server> npm run dev

> adminlte-server@0.0.1 dev
> set debug=* && ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/index.ts

[INFO] 11:39:24 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.6.3)
MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given. Supported drivers are: "aurora-mysql", "aurora-postgres", "better-sqlite3", "capacitor", "cockroachdb", "cordova", "expo", "mariadb", "mongodb", "mssql", "mysql", "nativescript", "oracle", "postgres", "react-native", "sap", "sqlite", "sqljs".
    at DriverFactory.create (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\src\driver\DriverFactory.ts:69:23)
    at new DataSource (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:136:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\adminlte-server\src\data-source.ts:5:30)  
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

Agradezco muchisimo cualquier ayuda compañeros

Comment: Mmmm, me parece que instalaste el paquete incorrecto `mysql` (este paquete no se actualiza hace más de 2 años). Elimina la dependencia de `mysql` y prueba instalando `npm i mysql2`.  Eso debería resolver el problema. Esto ocurre porque `mysql` introdujo un nuevo mecanismo de autenticación en las últimas versiones y los paquetes que no se han actualizado no la soportan. Hay una manera de desactivar el nuevo mecanismo en la base de datos pero no es para nada recomendado. Me haces saber si se resolvió el problema.

Comment: Hola, desinstale la dependencia mysql e instale mysql2 y me sale otro error diferente, voy a editar el post de la pregunta para poner este error y que lo puedas ver

Comment: No se si eso tenga que ver, con lo que tienes debería funcionar, pero convierte `ormconfig.json` en un archivo `.ts` y usa [este formato](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4068#issuecomment-655963645) para exportar la configuración. Según la [documentación oficial](https://typeorm.io/#:~:text=npm%20install%20mysql%20%2D%2Dsave%20(you%20can%20install%20mysql2%20instead%20as%20well)) `mysql2` está sorportado.

Comment: A menos que tengas un `npm` < 5 y te haya faltado poner el save en el comando que te puse `npm install mysql2 --save`

Comment: Lo conseguí brother, me ilumino un poco el post donde esta el formato, voy hacer una segunda edición en el post de la pregunta para dar la solución  y hacerte o hacerles a los demas compañeros una ultima pregunta para una duda que me surgió del resultado que me dio. La verdad es que lo intente todo y ninguna solución de internet me sirvió asi que espero que esto sirva para otros que tengan el mismo problema

Comment: No edites la pregunta, respóndete tu mismo. Eso es totalmente válido en stackoverflow. Luego, creas otra pregunta para lo otro que quieras preguntar.

Comment: Seguro? Es que la ves pasada eso hice, me respondí a mi propia pregunta y los admin me cerraron el post completo

Comment: Si pero no te lo cierran por responderte tu mismo. Te lo cierran por preguntas incompletas o cuyos errores no pueden reproducirse, o falta de detalles, o por poner solo imágenes y no código.

Comment: Checa esto [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Listo. Perfecto ya respondí mi propia pregunta con la solución y la nueva duda que se presento

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la solución.
Antes de darla este fue el código que use para crear el proyecto con **"typeORM"**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Después instale algunas dependencias que voy a necesitar y types:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

resulta que el proyecto no me creo el archivo ormconfig.json con la configuración, entonces me toco crear y configurarlo manualmente, sin embargo parece que este archivo no se está tomando para tener esa conexión con la base de datos Mysql workbench version 8 (error de principiante tal vez). Esta es la estructuria inicial del proyecto creado con typeORM y la configuracion del archivo ormconfig.json:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces gracias al post del compañero @JaimeMenendez me di cuenta que en el archivo  data-source.ts no había agregado los datos para conectar con mi base de datos (estos datos estaban todos por defecto), entonces eso hice, agregue el usuario, la contraseña, el nombre de la base de datos, el tipo, el host y el puerto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por esto era que no tenia los permisos para conectarme con la base de datos en workbench. Ahora mi duda es la siguiente, en la ejecución si observan en la siguiente imagen a que se debe que `express:router use '/' query +` salga en rojo?:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como sugerencia, por favor, los comandos de instalación y ese tipo de cosas cópialos a texto. Las capturas de los comandos se ven mal y cuesta leerlas. En cuanto a los colores, pues no hay mensaje de error ni advertencia ni nada, no creo que sea nada importante más que  el color de DEBUG que eligieron para los `middlewares`. Nota que solo ocurre en los `use`.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, para realizar una buena respuesta porfavor lee el siguiente foro: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Que pena, tienes razón. La verdad fue porque tenia las imagenes a la mano, pero la cuestión es mejorar entonces lo tendré en cuenta la próxima vez. Jaime muchas gracias por la ayuda :D. La letra en rojo si es cuestión del color en como esta programado el mensaje